# Swift 4 - How to import AppDelegate in a pods class

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to add this code to a view controller inside a cocoapods library

```
 public override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
     (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).restrictRotation = .portrait
}
```

but it gets a Use of undeclared type 'AppDelegate' error.. how can I import my project files such as AppDelegate into pods?

Answer (score 4):

A Pod should be reusable in different projects, so you wouldn't include project files in the Pod.

You should be able to achieve what you are after by having your pod define a protocol that is then adopted by your project App Delegate:

```
protocol RotationRestrictable {
    enum RotationRestriction {
        case .none
        case .portrait
        case .landscape
    }

    var restrictRotation: RotationRestriction
}
```

then you can say

```
public override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? RotationRestrictable {
        delegate.restrictRotation = .portrait
    }
}
```

And in your App Delegate:

```
import YourPod

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, RotationRestrictable {

    var restrictRotation: RotationRestrictable.RotationRestriction = .none {
        didSet {
           // Whatever you need to do
        }
    }
 ...
}
```